# Wrong CurrentCulture when running an nUnit test in TeamCity

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, teamcity, currentculture

I have a unit-test that relies on a specific culture.

In FixtureSetup, I set both `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` to the desired value (en-US).

When I run the test from Resharper, it passes.

When I run the test from TeamCity (using the runner "NUnit 2.4.6"), the test fails, because 
`CurrentCulture` is `cs-CZ` (the culture of my OS). However `CurrentUICulture` is still `en-US`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can force a specific culture for running your tests in your current thread `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread`

```
// set CurrentCulture to Invariant
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
// set UI culture to invariant
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

You can also use `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo` to provide the culture you want to use. This can be down in the `SetUp` part of your tests.

Remember to restore the culture to the previous one in your `TearDown` to ensure isolation

```
[TestFixture]
class MyTest {
  CultureInfo savedCulture;

  [SetUp]
  public void SetUp() {
    savedCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
  }

  [TearDown]
  public void TearDown() {
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = savedCulture;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have done. It works when running my unit-tests in Resharper, it doesn't when I run them in TeamCity.

Comment: How do you run nUnit in TeamCity ?

Comment: Have you tried using the `[SetCulture("en-US")]` attribute ? [http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setCulture&r=2.5.9](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setCulture&r=2.5.9)

Comment: have you tried to define your AssemblyCulture in the `AssemblyInfo.cs`?
`[assembly: AssemblyCulture("en-US")]`

Answer (score 3):

It seems like TeamCity is running FixtureSetup and unit-test in different threads, or somehow modifying `CurrentUICulture`.

Setting both `CurrentUICulture` and `CurrentCulture` in `SetUp` (instead of `FixtureSetup`) solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with NUnit 2.4.2, you can use the SetCulture Attribute.

```
namespace NUnit.Tests
{
  using System;
  using NUnit.Framework;

  [TestFixture]
  [SetCulture("fr-FR")]
  public class FrenchCultureTests
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The example is taken from the link below. Please also refer to the link for further details.

https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetCulture-Attribute

Answer (score 1):

In my test I've set and reset CurrentUICulture within individual test method

```
            var tempCurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
            try
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("zh-HK" );
                 actual = target.MethodToTest(resourceSet, localeId);
            }
            finally
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = tempCurrentUICulture;
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to restore the culture? I tried quickly and it seems to me that the NUnit framework restores the culture so it doesn't leak into other tests.

Comment: May be NUnit does better isolation between different tests. I had a problem with Microsoft Tests when running VSTest.Console.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. TeamCity somehow ignores CultureInfo instances I pass on the fly. Same tests and methods have been working as expected on all other platforms and runners (resharper, mstest, ncrunch and many more.) for almost 15 years. My case is not about managing culture contexts (UICulture, Thread, SetCulture etc.). It must be messing with .NET framework configurations or something. Confusing.

```
[Test]
public void WhatIsGoingOnWithTheCulture()
{
     //This method should pass. It should return "İ", it is Turkish letter.
     Assert.AreEqual("İ","i".ToUpper(new CultureInfo("tr-TR")));
}

//String lengths are both 1. Strings differ at index 0.
//  Expected: "Ý"
//  But was:  "İ"
```

TeamCity: 2020.2 (build 85487), tests with Nunit3 and NUnitConsole 3.11.1

.Net Framework 4.8